# What is the process to start jupyterhub automatically?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have installed a jupyterhub on my subdomain. Whenever I have to use jupyterhub I have to run a command **jupyterhub** on ubuntu terminal if it is closed we are not able to access it.

SO, is there any way to start jupyterhub automatically when system start?

Version:
 UBUNTU 16.4,
 anaconda 5.1.0,
 jupyter notebook --version 5.4.0,

Comment: Check out this: 

https://github.com/pradeeppathak9/infrastructure/tree/master/jhub

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this - what you are essentially looking for is how to run a script or start a service at system boot.

Depending on your comfort level with unix you can choose which option you want.

1. http://upstart.ubuntu.com/
2. configure jupyter as a service and start the service at boot time

[setup jupyter notebook as a service](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/setting-up-jupyter-notebook-server-as-service-in-ubuntu-16-04/)

[start service at system reboot](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples)